# Visual Studio 2019- I can't debug a JavaScript function in an ASPX file

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, google-chrome

I'm trying to debug a JS client function in Visual Studio.
I disabled debugging "Just My Code", and I attached the chrome process using my webpage to the debugger.
The breakpoint still show the following message:
"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line. Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type"

Here is the function being called (in the select element, 'onchange=OnSelectFlowChange(this)':

Fraud Check
        Exemption
        Visa Interchage Fees
        Mastercard Interchage Fees
        Visa Scheme Fees
        Mastercard Scheme Fees

Here is the function itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSelectFlowChange(parameters) {
        console.log("HiddenvValBefore changed-",document.getElementById("flowIdHidden"));
        console.log("parameters",parameters);
        console.log("Current selection value - ",parameters.value);
        var li = document.getElementById("listItemSelection");
        console.log("li", li.firstChild.value);
        document.getElementById("flowIdHidden").value = li.firstChild.value;
        console.log("hiddenvVal After-", document.getElementById("flowIdHidden"));

        if (theSection !== "") {
            console.log("in the section if");
            $(".bank").load(theSection + "/default.aspx?flowid=" + parameters.value, buildBank);
            $(".editor").load(theSection + "/Edit.aspx?flowId=" +  document.getElementById("listItemSelection").firstChild.value, function () {
                theID = 0;
                initializeEditor();
            });
        }
       
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Austin I edited the post and added the relevant code, there is no condition in there (besides the select element)

Comment: @Austin The first line of the function:
"console.log("HiddenvValBefore changed-",document.getElementById("flowIdHidden"));"

Comment: @Austin It's already set to FULL, still the same situation